Minimally change matrix with determinant 0
In the following matrix equation, all coefficients $a_{ij}>0$ and all $a_i>0$ and the column sums in the matrix $A$ are all 0 
(e.g. $-a_{11}+a_{21}+a_{31}=0$, etc.).
This means that
the determinant of $A$ is 0: $|A| = 0$.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & -a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & -a_{33} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-a_1\\
-a_2\\
-a_3\\\end{pmatrix}
$$
Conjecture:
If you now change the matrix $A$ by subtracting any value $d_i$ in the main diagonal (all $d_i>0$), the changed matrix equation only ever has a positive (i.e. all $x_i>0$) solution.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-a_{11}-d_1 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & -a_{22}-d_2 & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & -a_{33}-d_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-a_1\\
-a_2\\
-a_3\\\end{pmatrix}
$$
Question 1: 
Is this conjecture correct or can it be found somewhere on the Internet as a lemma?
Question 2:
Can the conjecture also be generalized to $n\times n$ matrices ($n>3$)?

It looks like your hypotheses can never hold. If you multiply both sides of your matrix equation on the left by the row vector $(1,\ 1,\ 1)$ and use associativity, then you find that $-a_1-a_2-a_3=0$, which contradicts all $a_i>0$.

Yes, this is true for all dimensions. It follows from the theory of M-matrices. The property that the columns sum to zero is enough to prove that $-A$ is a (singular) M-matrix, and then adding a positive diagonal matrix $D$ to it produces a (nonsingular) M-matrix. And the inverse of an M-matrix has non-negative elements.
A standard book on that topic is

Berman, Abraham; Plemmons, Robert J., Nonnegative matrices in the mathematical sciences, Classics in Applied Mathematics. 9. Philadelphia, PA: SIAM,. xx, 340 p. (1994). ZBL0815.15016.

